# How i save content which i insert in form field after reload a page the form field remain filled

Tags: php, html

i have some field like Firstname, Lastname , Country on country field i have add button to store  country name in database if user add country then filled fields blank after reload a page

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `hidden` input fields to store move the data along with HTML navigation.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

However, this is crude method and should be used only if data is not sensitive. A better approach will be to use `SESSION` variables.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you can only do this with ajax.

You would have to submit the form in the background via ajax (for example onKeyDown) and store the values somewhere ($_SESSION).

When your page reloads you can fill in the values from the session.

Comment: Yes am doing with ajax